# Using WebListener or OWIN as API Gateway for azure service fabric

Tags: owin, azure-service-fabric, kestrel-http-server, weblistener

We have 4 stateless services microservice in service fabrics which are using Kestrel as server. We need to expose those 4 services to the front end and have question regarding either to use WebListener or OWIN as server. Can any one tell which is better for performance. And also we have authentication service which is used to handle tokens.

Comment: What do you mean weblistener vs owin? Do you mean kestrel vs weblistener?

Comment: OWIN defines a standard interface between .NET web servers and web applications. It is not web server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By OWIN I'm assuming you're referring to [Katana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana) with Web API 2, which both implement OWIN.

In that case, the choice is really between "classic" Web API 2 with Katana and the newer ASP.NET Core with WebListener. I always recommend ASP.NET Core with WebListener for a few reasons:

- We have official [integration NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.WebListener/) for ASP.NET Core in Service Fabric
- These packages and their use cases are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#weblistener-in-reliable-services)
- Katana was largely a prototype for what would become ASP.NET Core. Most, if not all, new feature work is going into ASP.NET Core, not Katana, and ASP.NET Core is officially supported by Microsoft.

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.0 has HTTP.Sys Web-server instead WebListener in 1.*. Are there SF integration packages for it? Why not use Kestrel?

Comment: Ok, I got it, there are. Second question is still actual.