# Are Service Fabric Katana with Web API Projects Supported By Microsoft?

Tags: azure, owin, azure-service-fabric, katana

Regarding the switch from the Katana / Web API project template to ASP.NET Core for Service Fabric in Visual Studio 2017 that happened around April [Vaclav Turecek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4849191/vaclav-turecek) made this comment on a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478809/using-weblistener-or-owin-as-api-gateway-for-azure-service-fabric)...

> Katana was largely a prototype for what would become ASP.NET Core. Most, if not all, new feature work is going into ASP.NET Core, not Katana, and **ASP.NET Core is officially supported by Microsoft**.

Does this mean that the previous project template that used Katana / Owin is **not** officially supported by Microsoft?

How critical is it to migrate any Azure Service Fabric services we wrote using that old template to the new ASP.NET Core template?

Are the old Katana based services acceptable for production?

If we continue to use these old services should we expect any issues?  For example, what about automated deployments with Team Services?  ASP.NET Core doesn't require XML transforms for it's configurations during deployment but the older Service Fabric template uses web.config so it does.  Can we expect this to cause headaches that migrating to ASP.NET would cure?